# Refresh gallery after download file from url

Tags: android, eclipse, image, gallery

I have imageView, if imageView click by user apps will download image where the url have been setting. after that, image will be downloaded at '/sdcard/koen' if the folder exist then image will go there if not then folder will create.

I can download the file, i check from apps 'fileManager'. there's image where i download in that folder. but when i check in gallery i can't see the image.

but, if I move the image from that folder to somewhere folder. Then image show in gallery.

this is my code so far:

```
networkimageview.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean success = (new File("/sdcard/koen")).mkdir(); 
            if (!success)
            {
                Log.w("directory not created", "directory not created");
            }

            try
            {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Tampil_Produk_Fragment.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Download Gambar. . . ");
                progressDialog.show();
                URL url = new URL(foto_produk);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                String data1 = String.valueOf(String.format("/sdcard/koen/%d.jpg",System.currentTimeMillis()));

                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(data1);

                ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outstream);
                byte[] byteArray = outstream.toByteArray();

                stream.write(byteArray);
                stream.flush();
                stream.getFD().sync();
                scanFile(data1);
                stream.close();
                if(progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing())
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
 }
```

The problem is, i have added code :

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/koen/"))));
```

but still no luck, how to refresh gallery after download file and show up that image in gallery?

I have edited my code, thats my code now. it will show the image to gallery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have added code... but still no luck

Try pointing to the actual file, not to a directory. Or, use `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method.

Also, call `flush()` and `getFD().sync()` before `close()` on your `FileOutputStream()`.

In addition, you are doing network I/O on the main application thread. Your app will crash on Android 4.0+ devices, and it will suck on all the rest as you freeze the UI. Please move your network I/O to a background thread, or use any number of [third-party libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) that can download your image for you asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks sir, now my image showing in gallery after i download image. i use MediaScannerConnection like you said.

but, for a download image. Like you said, I freeze the UI. If I use AsyncTask(doInBackground) is enough?